# Cannot resolve manager type when using django-polymorphic with mypy django-stubs

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mypy, django-polymorphic

I'm trying to use django-polymorphic to extend a DRF project that uses typeddjango with mypy-stubs. I recently started to use PolymorphicModels and mypy instantly started to complain and throw errors:

```
error: Could not resolve manager type for "<MyModel>.objects"
```

I included `"polymorphic"` and `"django.contrib.contenttypes"` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` of the project, and can't really make sense of why mypy keeps complaining. I read about inherited managers in the django-polymorphic doc which could be a cause for troubles, but I didn't manage to identify the root cause to find a fix.

I opened a ticket here: https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/issues/1158 with more details.
If anyone has some info, I'd love to hear..

Comment: In `django-stubs`, this error is most often caused by models that inherit from Any (when base class is not a `models.Model` subclass from `mypy` point of view). Solution is not invented yet, AFAIC. Since this happens often, I'll try to fix it, if I have enough free time, your contribution is welcome! Currently plugin heavily depends on the fact that model classes inherit from `models.Model` and adds managers only to those classes. I suppose that one solution may be to provide `is_model` decorator in `django_stubs_ext` to declare models inheriting from `Any`.

Comment: Thank you for jumping in @SUTerliakov.
Up until now I did not really dig deep into `django-stubs` source. I checked `django-polymorphic` though, and it seems PolymorphicModel does not inherit from `Any`. It does inherit from `models.Model` (https://github.com/django-polymorphic/django-polymorphic/blob/master/polymorphic/models.py#L27)  however, it seems to have a custom metaclass: https://github.com/django-polymorphic/django-polymorphic/blob/master/polymorphic/base.py#L33, which - I'd believe - could mess with typing. Does that sound plausible to you or am I off?

Comment: Nothing inherits from Any in fact, but `django-polymorphic` is untyped package (no `py.typed` and no stub package), so most probably all imports are treated as Any in your setup. Try to `reveal_type(PolymorphicModel)` somewhere in your code to make sure it is the case. I tried on a sample project and `reveal_type(PolymorphicModel)` and `reveal_type(MyModel.objects)` both show `Any`.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you, I misunderstood (and wasn't looking at the right place). Yes, you're right indeed, I `reveal_type`'d and got `Any` in return. So yes, mypy defaults to Any here. If I write a stupid test script in VS Code; pretty much:
```python
from __future__ import annotations
from polymorphic.models import PolymorphicModel
from typing_extensions import reveal_type

reveal_type(PolymorphicModel)
```
I get `Type of "PolymorphicModel" is "Type[PolymorphicModel]" Pylance` however, which contradicts the `Any` I get when I `mypy` the testscript locally.